# convert values to keys in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have MongoDB documents for shirt size that have this shape:

```
{ "_id" : "L", "count" : 2.0 },
{ "_id" : "XL", "count" : 2.0 },
{ "_id" : "XXXL", "count" : 1.0 },
{ "_id" : "M", "count" : 1.0 }
```

How can I return a single document that follows these criteria:

- **Return values, not keys**
- **Order by shirt size label**
- **Convert floating point values to integers**
- **Return shirt size label with a 0 value when they don't exist**

Desired shape:

```
{
  S: 0,
  M: 1,
  L: 2,
  XL: 2,
  XXL: 0,
  XXXL: 1
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first push all the values in an array using [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage with `k` and `v` pair... Then extract the key value pair with [`arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) aggregation and finally you have to check for [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) condition for every sizes

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "array": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$_id",
        "v": "$count"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$array" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "S": { "$ifNull": ["$S", 0] },
    "M": { "$ifNull": ["$M", 0] },
    "L": { "$ifNull": ["$L", 0] },
    "XL": { "$ifNull": ["$XL",0]},
    "XXL": { "$ifNull": ["$XXL", 0]},
    "XXXL": { "$ifNull": ["$XXXL", 0] }
  }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "L": 2,
    "M": 1,
    "S": 0,
    "XL": 2,
    "XXL": 0,
    "XXXL": 1
  }
]
```

Check it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RBZjHXm16u5)

Answer (score 3):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            obj: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$count" } },
            keys: { $push: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            obj: {
                $map: {
                    input: [ "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL" ],
                    as: "key",
                    in: {
                        $let: {  
                            vars: { keyIndex: { $indexOfArray: [ "$keys", "$$key" ] } },
                            in: {
                                $cond: {
                                    if: { $eq: [ "$$keyIndex", -1 ] },
                                    then: { k: "$$key", v: 0 },
                                    else: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$obj", "$$keyIndex" ] }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$obj" }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically you should start with accumulating all keys and values into one object using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with `_id` set to `null`. Then to enforce the order of keys that you need you can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) with constant array as an input. Mapping should check if each size exists in input data (using [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) - returns `-1` otherwise) and take that value ([$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html)) or create default with `0` otherwise. Branching logic can be achieved with [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html).

In the last pipeline stage you can use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to convert that array of `k-v` pairs into single object and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote that object to root level.

Answer (score 0):

Without Aggragate:

```
RS-LAB:PRIMARY> db.shirtSize.find()
{ "_id" : "L", "count" : "2.0" }
{ "_id" : "XL", "count" : "2.0" }
{ "_id" : "XXXL", "count" : "1.0" }
{ "_id" : "M", "count" : "1.0" }
{ "_id" : "S", "count" : null }

RS-LAB:PRIMARY> 
db.shirtSize.find().sort({"count":1}).forEach(function(myShirts) { if 
(myShirts.count == null) {x = "0.0";} else {x = myShirts.count;} 
print(myShirts._id+"\t:\t"+parseInt(x));})

S   :   0
XXXL    :   1
M   :   1
L   :   2
XL  :   2
```